# is cloudflare being attacked?

Tags: cloudflare

this was the only place I could think to go to, so I went to one of my servers/websites that use Cloudflare and it just wasn't working so I wanted to ask the lovely people of this community what is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cloudflare is experiencing issues at the moment.
Source: https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare *could* be being DDoSed, but maybe not. Their status page says they have started to implement a fix.
[image: internet of fire]